# replacing list item in unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

I am Lerner in Jquery.

```
<ul id="draglist">
 <li>item1</li>
 <li>item2</li>
 <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="droplist"> </ul>
```

I have above 2 lists .

```
  $(function() {

             $( "#draglist" ).sortable({appendTo: "body", helper:  "clone"});
             $( "#draglist" ).disableSelection();
             $( "#droplist" ).droppable(
                        {  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                              hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                              accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                              drop: function( event, ui ) {

                                  var aa=ui.draggable.text();
                                  alert(aa);
                                  $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                                  $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );

                        }
             });
  });
```

this code snippet makes my draglist draggeble and droplist droppable. When i drop an item , it will append an item to list . But i want replace the existing element , when i drop an element into second list. How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your drop function `$("#droplist").children().remove();` 
The result should look like this:

```
$(function () {

    $("#draglist").sortable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#draglist").disableSelection();
    $("#droplist").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $("#droplist").children().remove();
            var aa = ui.draggable.text();
            alert(aa);
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);



        }

    });


});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpxb7/)